# Laravel and Mysql three tables relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to add three tables to MySql but I don't know how to organize them.

My tables are :

- apartment
- floor
- surface

And my relations :

- apartment can have many floor
- apartment can have many surfaces
- floor can have many apartment
- floor can have many surfaces
- surfaces can have one floor (inside apartment's floors)
- surfaces can have one apartment

Surfaces are enter after apartment, so I can't use surfaces floor as my apartment floor.

At the moment I have apartment table and floor table with a pivot table (many to many).

In Mysql, what's the best way to handle this ? And after inside laravel ?

Thank for yourhelp !

Edit : my work on laravel so far (only floor table and apartment table)

In Apartment.php :

```
public function floors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Floor');
}
```

In Floor.php :

```
public function apartments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Copro\Apartment');
}
```

Edit 2 : my migration so far :

```
    Schema::create('surfaces', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('apartment_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('apartment_id')->references('id')->on('apartments')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('floor_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('floor_id')->references('id')->on('floors')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->decimal('surface',65, 3);
    });

   Schema::create('apartments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
    });

   Schema::create('floors', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
    });

    Schema::create('apartment_floor', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('apartment_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('floor_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('apartment_id')->references('id')->on('apartments')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('floor_id')->references('id')->on('floors')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: Please post whatever you have done in Laravel and we will help you based on that. I mean to say the table structure or model structure etc.. Thanks.

Comment: Update with my work

Answer (score 0):

I can think of below kind of relationships in Laravel, I have not created the sample code although but it should help.

Apartment model:

```
public function floors() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Floor', 'floor_id', 'id');
} /* Many apartments belong to single floor. Single floor can have many apartments.*/

public function surfaces() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Surface', 'surface_id', 'id');
} /* Single apartment has many surfaces */
```

---

Floor model:

```
public function apartments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Apartment', 'apartment_id', 'id');
} /* A floor has many apartments */

public function surfaces() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Surface', 'surface_id', 'id');
} /* A floor has many surfaces */
```

---

Surface model:

```
public function floor() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Copro\Floor', 'floor_id', 'id');
} /* Surfaces belong to single floor */

public function apartment() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Copro\Apartment', 'apartment_id', 'id');
} /* Surfaces belong to single apartment */
```

**However**, it will bring more clarity to the answers if you can provide table schema or migration schema on the same question. Also, you can mention which kinds of SQL queries you are expecting and want to execute. Thanks. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I am not having PHP installed right now but below schema can be useful to us to at least give newer and better thoughts.

```
Floor:
    id
    flr_number
```

---

```
Apartment:
    id
    apt_number
    flr_id
```

---

```
Surface:
    id
    apt_id
    surface
```

---

*Floor will have many apartments through surfaces*. Therefore we can introduce below method in Floor model.

```
public function surfaces() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Copro\Surface',
        'App\Models\Copro\Apartment',
        'flr_id', /* Foreign key of Apartments table */
        'apt_id', /* Foreign key of Surfaces table */
        'id', /* Local key of Floors table */
        'id' /* Local key of Apartments table */
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer !

However I don't have migration yet because I don't know how to structure my tables

Comment: Maybe if I do a polymorphism between apartment / floor and surface / floor and I had apartmen_id to my surface table.

Comment: @Furya - another thing I can think of is to use "hasManyThrough" because floor has many surfaces through apartments. That relationship can be used as well.

Comment: I post my migration. Do you think it's ok or must I use polymorphism between my 3 tables and keep apartment_id inside surfaces ?

Comment: @Furya - I have edited my answer and given `hasManyThrough` example. You can take a look.

Comment: Thank for your help but apartment can have many floors. Must I create a pivot table ?

Comment: And how to know wich floor form apartment, surface is ?

Comment: How can single apartment has many floors? 1 apartment can belong to 1 floor only, isn't it?

Comment: No an apartment can have many floors, for example here in france we call that "duplex".

Comment: Makes sense, so you need to keep "apartment_floor" but can you modify "surfaces" schema like below?
`Schema::create('surfaces', function (Blueprint $table) {   
    $table->increments('id');
 $table->integer('apartment_floor_id')->unsigned()->index();
 $table->decimal('surface',65, 3);
});`

Comment: So I make a pivot table between apartment and floor and I use that id inside surfaces table ?

Comment: And for MySQL constraints, what can I do ?

Comment: You can set foreign key `apartment_floor_id` in `surfaces` table which points to `apartment_floor` table's primary key.

Comment: Hey @Furya - let me know if this discussions has helped. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. I try your code and how to retrieve apartment id from surface ?

Comment: `$surfaces = Surfaces :: with('apartment')->get();` - Try this.

Comment: With relationships you add to your post ?

Comment: Many surfaces belong to single apartment.

Comment: Even if I don't have apartment_id on my table but my apartment_floor_id ?

Comment: I need apartment_id on my surface table ?

Comment: You may use `hasManyThrough` as per my last code segment in the answer.